# Select from multiple tables using WHERE from another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, partitioning

I've got a table about 600 GB and it is partitioned

```
CREATE TABLE oper.facts 
(   
    row_id varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    load_id varchar(500) NULL,
    calc_start_dt timestamp NULL,
    calc_end_dt timestamp NULL,
    direction_id int4 NULL,
    is_dash_metric bool NULL,
    is_dash_metric_for_partition bool NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT f_facts_pkey1 
        PRIMARY KEY (row_id, is_dash_metric_for_partition)
)   
PARTITION BY LIST (is_dash_metric_for_partition);   

CREATE INDEX facts_calc_start_dt_idx ON ONLY oper.facts USING btree (calc_start_dt);    

CREATE INDEX facts_load_id_idx ON ONLY oper.facts USING btree (load_id);
```

Partition is made by column BY LIST (is_dash_metric_for_partition) for the purpose of logical replication. Because we don't replicate the whole table, only part of it where  column `is_dash_metric_for_partition` is true.

So our table is growing and we what to make subpartition. But the thing is that users in there query use column load_id. And major part of queries look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM oper.facts 
WHERE load_id IN ('149256000000_20230126_20230127', '152111_20230128_20230128');
```

As you can see column `load_id` is combined from 3 parts - first number of project in this case 149256000000 and 152111 (from first and second condition). And the second and third part is a date start of project and date end. Date start and date end are columns `calc_start_dt` and `calc_end_dt` in table `oper.facts`.

So I want to make subpartitions by for example column `calc_start_dt` and the main point I want to create a view for users `oper.vw_facts`, from which they can query results using `WHERE` by column `load_id`.

So first step in future view should be - parsing condition `WHERE` by column `load_id`. If there is a column `load_id` in `WHERE`, then get `date_start` from it.

For example if `load_id` is '152111_20230128_20230128' and '149256000000_20230126_20230127'. Then next step in view should be searching not in whole table `oper.facts`, but only in special subpartition `oper.facts_is_dash_20230126` and `oper.facts_is_dash_20230128`.

But how can I parse condition where in first where for column `load_id`?

And then if I don't find `load_id` in `where`, do the normal search - sec scan on table `oper.facts`, but if I find condition by `load_id`, then parse `date_start` and then search if exists subpartition with range partition with `date_start`, and then the main point - build select from several tables

Comment: Would the *hash sub-partitioning* on the column `load_id` be an option?

Comment: Marmite Bomber, I don't know for sure. Didnt use it before. I need partitions be more or less equal by rows. Load_id is a combine value, not sure for now. Need to be tested)))